# Restrict backspace in textbox Javascript

Tags: javascript, textbox

I need to restrict numbers and backspace in a textbox so users can't edit their answers. I got the numbers to work, but the backspace can still be used with the code below. I am not sure why '\b' isn't working in JavaScript. I have also tried making the event 'keydown' instead of 'input' but that doesn't work also. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
function lettersOnly(input) {
  var regex = /([0-9\b])/g;
  var input = event.target;
  input.value = input.value.replace(regex, "");}

document.querySelector("#survey-input").addEventListener('input', lettersOnly)
```

**Update:**
This is what I came up with and it works for me!

```
//function for no numbers in textbox
function lettersOnly(input) {
  var regex = /[0-9]/i;
  var input = event.target;
  input.value = input.value.replace(regex, "");}

//function for restricting backspace   
function preventBackspace(e) {
        var evt = e || window.event;
        if (evt) {
            var keyCode = evt.charCode || evt.keyCode;
            if (keyCode == 8){
                if (evt.preventDefault) {
                    evt.preventDefault();
                } else {
                    evt.returnValue = false;}}}}

document.querySelector("#survey-input").addEventListener('keydown', preventBackspace)
document.querySelector("#survey-input").addEventListener('input', lettersOnly)
```

Comment: use `keydown` instead of input to handle the backspace.

Comment: Just disabling backspace doesn't prevent edit ability. Can put cursor at beginning and select all and delete it, can paste etc

Comment: Thank you @GetOffMyLawn but this doesn't seem to work. Do you have any other suggestions?